# Как получить название токена по адресу?

Tags: javascript, node.js, криптография, smart-contract

Как мне по адресу получить название токена?
Например есть адрес смарт контракта в сети bsc

```
const tokenName = await  getTokenNameByAdress('0x7130d2A12B9BCbFAe4f2634d864A1Ee1Ce3Ead9c');

console.log(tokenName) // BTCB
```

Возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 0):

В общем нашёл решение с помощью библиотеки web3

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3Bsc = new Web3("https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443");

const ABI = [...] // ERC-20 ABI JSON можно найти в интернете

// The token contract address
const ADDRESS_BSC = "0x7130d2A12B9BCbFAe4f2634d864A1Ee1Ce3Ead9c";    

async function run() {
    const contract = new web3Bsc.eth.Contract(ABI, ADDRESS_BSC);
    const name = await contract.methods.name().call();
    console.log("name:", name);
    const symbol = await contract.methods.symbol().call();
    console.log("symbol:", symbol);
    const decimals = await contract.methods.decimals().call();
    console.log("decimals:", decimals);
}
run()
```

Comment: Ну, да - работая со стандартом, бывает, неплохо его таки прочитать :-)